# First order linear ODE with some decay condition

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

In Kronheimer [1, p.183], a certain statement is made of which I extract the following special case.

> Let $\alpha:\mathbb{R}\to \mathrm{Mat}(n\times n,\mathbb{C})$ be smooth and suppose that there exist $C,a>0$ and a diagonal matrix $H$ such that
>   $$\|\alpha(t)-H\|<Ce^{-at}$$
>   for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, there is a solution to the differential equation
>   $$g(t)\alpha(t)g(t)^{-1}-\dot{g}(t)g(t)^{-1}=H,\quad(g(t)\in\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})),$$
>   such that
>   $$\lim_{t\to\infty}g(t)=1.$$

I see that this is just a first-order linear ODE and hence solutions exist globally, but I don't see why there must be a solution converging to $1$. There is no justification in the paper. How do we prove this?

*Reference.*

[1] Kronheimer, P., *Instantons and the geometry of the nilpotent variety,* J. Differential Geometry **32** (1990) 473-490.

Comment: 1 means identity here ?

Comment: @PiyushGrover Yes.

Comment: This should be easy if $a$ dominates the entries of $H$, and in general, I'm not even sure right now it's true (though it well might be).